# Data Structures (Weiss Java book): Why allocate Comparable[] in BinaryHeap<T> array instead of T[]?

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, binary-heap

I'm taking a data structures course, and we're using Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in Java 2nd Edition by Mark Weiss. In his BinaryHeap implementation, his constructor creates a Comparable[] array that is casted to AnyType[]. Do you have any idea as to why he does this instead of just creating a new AnyType[]?

I understand the structure of the BinaryHeap, but I want to be up to speed on generics. The class declaration is straightforward enough, make sure that AnyType extends a type that is Comparable to AnyType or any superclass up AnyType's inheritance hierarchy (in case AnyType is a subclass of a type and doesn't need to change its compareTo method in order to function).

However, the line, `array = (AnyType[]) new Comparable[ capacity + 1 ];`, makes no sense to me. Isn't AnyType already a Comparable? What ramifications are there for just writing `array = new AnyType[ capacity + 1 ];`?

The full class source can be found [on his site](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~weiss/dsaajava2/code/BinaryHeap.java), but here are the parts I'm concerned with:

```
public class BinaryHeap<AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>>
{
    private int currentSize;      // Number of elements in heap
    private AnyType [ ] array; // The heap array

    /**
     * Construct the binary heap.
     * @param capacity the capacity of the binary heap.
     */
    public BinaryHeap( int capacity )
    {
        currentSize = 0;
        array = (AnyType[]) new Comparable[ capacity + 1 ];
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create arrays of a generic type because the type information doesn't exist at runtime. As `AnyType` extends `Comparable`, that is the only 'concrete' type that can be used.

The cast to `AnyType[]` is simply to ensure compile-time warnings are given if there's a mistake; that cast won't exist in the resulting bytecode instructions. Similarly, the `array` class variable will be a `Comparable[]` in the resulting bytecode.

Answer (score 2):

Java uses [Type Erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) to implement Generics so at run time the type AnyType isn't known and therefore you can't create an array of them. Look at this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation).

Answer (score 1):

Because of generic type erasure, the compiler has has no idea what `AnyType` is (and hence can't create an array of it). But we know `AnyType` implements `Comparable`, so creating an array of Comparables is a safe solution.